# extract string within double quote from the line in a file

Tags: perl

I have the file with content as :

```
Component (0463) "commonfiles"
Component (0464) "demo_new_comp"
Component (0467) "test_comp" (removed)
Component (0469) "test_comp3" (removed)
Component (0465) "textfiles1
```

Need to extract string within double quotes from each line having (removed) and place in a array.
My code is:

```
my $fh = new IO::File;
$fh->open("<comp.log") or die "Cannot open comp.log";
my @comp_items;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /removed/ ) {;
        my $compName = $_ = ~ m/"(.*?)"/;
        print " Componnet Name : \"$compName\"\n";
    }
}
```

I am not getting the correct output giving some numbers as:

```
"18446744073709551614"
"18446744073709551614"
```

Output should be :

```
test_comp
test_comp3
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `my ( $compName ) = ...`?

Answer (score 7):

```
my $compName = $_ = ~ m/"(.*?)"/;
```

`= ~` is not same as `=~` but assignment and [bitwise negation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators)

and what you want is,

```
my ($compName) = $_ =~ m/"(.*?)"/;
```

or just,

```
my ($compName) = /"(.*?)"/;
```

Comment: this gives the output as :Componnet Name : "1"Componnet Name : "1"

Comment: If that's the answer, please mark this answer as correct.